# Javascript getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the getElementsByTagName("a") method to get all the elements under a specific tag.

However, I don't want every anchor tag. How would I narrow it so I only select all the anchor tags under the the ul tag for "someListClass" name?

`<ul class="someListClass"> <li><a href... /></li>... </ul>`

I know in jQuery you can just select with $(".someListClass a").

How would I do it ***without*** using jQuery?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Give your ul an id and then use

```
<ul id="ulid" class="someListClass"> <li><a href... /></li>... </ul>

document.getElementById ( "ulid" ).getElementsByTagName ( "a" );
```

[element.getElementsByTagName](https://web.archive.org/web/20130406050956/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)

```
elements = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
```

> **elements** is a live NodeList of found
>   elements in the order they appear in
>   the subtree.
>
> **element** is the element from where the
>   search should start. Note that only
>   the descendants of this element are
>   included in the search, but not the
>   element itself.
>
> **tagName** is the qualified name to look
>   for. The special string "*" represents
>   all elements. For compatibility with
>   XHTML, lower-case should be used.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
element.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
```

where element is the UL item... so grab the UL item then search against that. something like:

```
<ul class="someListClass" id="myList"> <li><a href... /></li>... </ul>

var theList = document.getElementById('myList');
var listItems = theList.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Answer (score 1):

you want getElementsByClassName http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/05/getelementsbycl.html

```
  links = document.getElementsByClassName("someListClass")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a framework, I can think of no other way than going though each element manually and to iterate its parents. If one of them has the class "somelistClass", add it to the stack. Otherwise, not.

If you are looking for the children of a single element, phoenix's approach is the way to go.