# How do I click a button without an id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I tried using document.getElementsByName but that didn't work for me.  I'm trying to click a button, but I can't use document.getElementById because it does not have an id.

This is the button:

```html
<div id="ApplyButton">
<br>
<br>
<input class="submitBtn" onclick="{ _onclick_1(arguments[0]);}" type="button" value="Apply">
</div>
```

Comment: provide the html example with the button which you want to click

Comment: Please put your html and javascript into the question, wrapped in code tags.

Comment: I added the html.

Comment: There are several questions already answering different ways to select elements in javascript. E.g. [this answer suggesting the `querySelector()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975881/how-to-select-element-that-does-not-have-specific-class), or [this one on how to use `selectElementsByClassName`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name). And [one discussing `getElementsByTagName`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666881/javascript-getelementsbytagname).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Document.getElementsByClassName()` to get it via class.

If you are using jQuery, you can use `$('.class-here')` or with custom attr like `$('[name="ElementNameHere"]').doStuff();`

You can replace name with any custom attr.